# ZF2 phpUnit test view helper

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework2, phpunit

Unfortunatelly i'm absolute zero in ZF2 and unit testing.
I wrote simple view helper(wrapper function of Zend Translate) and now i have to write a test for this. I'm trying to add one test in existing test class, so everything is configured ...maybe. I simply need to get to work this code:

```
public function testTranslation()
{
    $result = $this->t('about');
    $expected = "About";
    $this->assertEquals($exp, $res);
}
```

I also tried to get functionality like i do it in controllers, but no luck:

```
$t = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ViewHelperManager')->get('t');
$result = $t('about');
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create an instance of your view helper. The purpose of unit testing is to just test a single unit (your view helper in this case).

When you retrieve the helper from the serviceManager you'll need to bootstrap a full ZF2 application. Now you are not testing just the helper, but all the components involved. This is called integration testing.

Your unit test would look something like this:

```
public function testTranslation()
{
    $helper = new TranslateHelper();
    $result = $helper->__invoke('about');
    $expected = "About";
    $this->assertEquals($exp, $res);
}
```